# When does random forest feature importance fail?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, feature-selection

I'm curious about the assumptions of random forest feature importance.

In this [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1010933404324), the author says that

> "We show that random forest variable importance measures are a sensible means for variable selection in many applications, but are not reliable in situations where potential predictor variables vary in their scale of measurement or their number of categories."

I don't understand what it means by "predictor variables vary in their scale of measurement." Is this referring to the need to standardize data before fitting a random forest model?

1. Does RF based feature importance require standardization of features?
2. Does it require fitting a good RF model (ex: pruning), as if I'm making an actual prediction with RF?
3. What do I do if I have categorical variables and continuous variables at the same time? Is permutation method the only option?

Comment: I think this question is more suitable for [Data Science site](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) or [stack exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar posted there, did not get answers